# IntelliJ: breakpoint everytime an object appears in breakpoint

Tags: intellij-idea

I've noticed an unexpected behavior in an object used in this really complicate framework.

What I want is that the debugger stops (like with breakpoints) every time that the object appears in an instruction, without manually add breakpoints in all the instruction where it is used/appears.

Can I do something like this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Field Breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-field-watchpoints.html) is what you are looking for.

Read [breakpoint type overview](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/types-of-breakpoints.html#d1999342e59) to get an overview of the different breakpoint types.

Furthermore, it is possible to put a condition on a breakpoint - read [configure breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-breakpoints.html?origin=old_help).